# How to set the location that JavaCompiler executes from?

Tags: java, java-module, working-directory, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

I am working with [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html), using it to programmatically compile Java code from my running Java application. Everything is working great, except that I don't how to execute the compiler from outside the executing directory of my running Java application. More specifically, I am assuming that `javac`, and by extension, `JavaCompiler` can only reference paths relative to them, not absolute paths. Thus I don't know how to reference a path in another folder without knowing where that folder is relative to me at runtime.

Imagine my folder structure is as follows.

```
root
|
|--- f1 <-- my java application is running in this directory
|
|--- f2 <-- I want to compile code that is in here
```

If I was in the terminal, I would simply `cd` to the `f2` directory and do what I need to there. But I don't see how to accomplish this using `JavaCompiler`.

I tried to put the path of my source code in the compiler options, but the problem is, they only seem to operate relative to the location of where I am running the application from. Sure, I could do `--module-source-path=../f2`, but that just makes my solution brittle. I want to be able to tell `JavaCompiler` to execute in a specific directory, and then have it work from there.

Is this possible?

```java
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.util.List;

public class SOQ_20240225
{


   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      final JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
   
      final StandardJavaFileManager standardJavaFileManager = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

      final List<String> compilerOptions = List.of("ignore, setting module source path here");

      //What do I put here (if here) to get javac to execute in the directory I choose?
      //Or to point to that directory from wherever it is?
      //I assume I can only do relative paths, and not absolute paths.

      final var compilationTask = javac.getTask(null, null, null, compilerOptions, null, null);
   
      compilationTask.call();

   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javac` supports both relative paths and absolute paths. And thus, so do all of its compiler options too (for example, `--module-source-path` and the rest).

So, you could simply provide a `Path.toAbsolutePath()` to whatever directory you want, and things should work just fine.

`"--module-source-path=" + this.moduleSourcePath.toAbsolutePath()`

Again, you must use the `toAbsolutePath()`, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: “As long as you have the path to your current location” … You don’t.  There is no guarantee that the current directory contains your program.  Anyone could run your program using `java -jar C:\Users\david\Downloads\myapp.jar`, from any directory.  There is no safe way to rely on a relative directory.  At best, you can require that the program is invoked with the f2 path specified in a system property or as a command-line argument.

Comment: @VGR Maybe I am misunderstanding here. I know that `Path.of(".")` returns the location from where I called `java -jar`, even if the jar I am running is somewhere else entirely. And to my understanding, the `JavaCompiler` class operates from the same location as `Path.of(".")`, correct? Are you telling me that that is not true? I just tested it now, running a `.java` file from a wildly different directory, and it still worked doing the above method I subscribed. Is it only for jars? What am I missing? Or maybe this is bad vocab, where I am implying something different with "current directory".

Comment: “I know that Path.of(".") returns the location from where I called java -jar…” No, it does not.  The [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of a process, including a Java process, can be anywhere.  It’s entirely up to the person or program which starts Java, and your application has no control over it.  I can open a command window, do `cd /d %TEMP%`, then run your program using `java -jar C:\Users\david\Downloads\myapp.jar`.  If I did that, `Path.of(".").toAbsolutePath()` would return a directory which is nowhere near f1 or f2.

Comment: @VGR Ok, I think I found out where the confusion is. I recreated your example fully, down to the T. And I think I have been misinterpreting you this entire time. Understanding that now, I think I see where my inaccuracy is. So let me reattempt. We may not necessarily know exactly where we are, but the path returned by `Path.of(".")` is the exact same location that `JavaCompiler` will be basing itself out of. Therefore, you can use the location from `Path.of(".")` to be the caller for `relativize()`, and using that, your program should work, regardless of what `Path.of("*")` returns. Correct?

Comment: @VGR When I attempted your example though, the directory it outputted for `Path.of(".")` was "current directory = C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\." -- So even though I misunderstood your comment and I see how what I said was inaccurate, your example still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @VGR OH, you are taking issue with me saying a path to F1. Ok, yes, you have been trying to demonstrate this entire time that the application has no way to know where its compilation unit exists, only what directory the call to use that file is being performed from. In which case, yes, let me edit my answer.

Comment: @VGR Cleaned up the answer. Please let me know if my answer is fully correct now.

Comment: I’m not clear on what relativize accomplishes.  An absolute path would work just as well.  The real challenge is knowing where that path is to begin with, which, as I said, isn’t really possible.  Path.of(".") could return anything.

Comment: @VGR Well that is both annoying and surprising. I tried multiple times to get that working, as my first solution, but it did not work. Must have been a mistype or something. Regardless, you are correct. I will repurpose this solution to use just a direct path instead.

Comment: @VGR Edited my answer. Check for me once more?

Comment: @VGR didn't hear any response, so accepting for now.